# SSRS 2008 embedded image hide

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have an embedded image on my report and I would like to show/hide it based on a database field value. Could you please let me know how to achieve this? I tried to set Image properities 'Visibility' Show or Hide based on the following expression but I received an error message. It's not allowing me to save the report from Report Builder. Thanks for your help.

=`First(Fields!dbField.Value, "NEW")`

Comment: 1)Is "NEW" a group name? 2)Does this expression evaluate to "True" or "False"?

Comment: And that error message was...?

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do the trick

```
=IIf((First(Fields!dbField.Value) = "NEW"),True,False)
```